# Dynamically generating <Location /> constructs in Apache using mod_perl

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-perl

I need to have my Apache web-server serve a lot of sites through `<Location />` structures. The last thing I want is a massive file with every single `<Location />` structure for every single site in there (not even a generated one). I've been looking into `mod_rewrite` and some of the mass virtual hosting modules available for Apache but, unfortunately, I did not find what I was looking for.

The other day I was looking into `mod_perl` and as I understand it, I can use `mod_perl` to 'script' the Apache web server. This made me wonder if this is the solution I've been looking for? I've been searching around for specific examples to my problem but I can't seem to find anything specific.

My question is, to what extend can I have `mod_perl` generate my `<Location />` structures **at request time** and what sort of variables do I have access to while doing this?

**UPDATE**:

Just for clarity I'd like to give an example of the sort of thing that I'm trying to do. I know that the following example is not correct but I'm looking for a way to do something like this (at request time):

```
<Location /$1/$2>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Secure area"
   AuthUserFile /sites/$1/$2/users.file
</location>
```

So what I want is; Imagine that `$1` is the name of a department and that `$2` is the name of a project. If I would go the the url `mydomain.com/financial/accounts` that the `users.file` from the directory `/sites/financial/accounts` is used. Every location has a different `users.file` and if a url doesn't translate to a file system path, a normal 404 is shown or it just won't work. This way I can create a single `<location />` pattern without having to maintain a large amount of `<location />`s and to necessity to reload the server every time I make a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried your specific use case, but you might want to experiment with mod_perl and:

```
<Perl>
foreach (</sites/*/*/users.file>) {
    my $loc = $_;
    $loc =~ s/^\/sites(.*)\/users\.file/$1/;
    $Location{$loc} = {
        AuthType => "Basic",
        AuthName => "Secure area",
        AuthUserFile => $_,
    };
}
</Perl>
```

You will still have to reload Apache each time you add a new "users.file" though. If you really need to do it dynamically, you should build a PerlAuthenHandler instead:

```
<Location /> # we need for any request to the site
    PerlAuthenHandler MyApache2::DynamicAuthUserFile
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Secure area"
</Location>
```

and a `MyApache2/DynamicAuthUserFile.pm` script similar to this one:

```
package MyApache2::DynamicAuthUserFile;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Apache::RequestRec ();
use Apache::Access ();

use Apache::Const -compile => qw(OK DECLINED);

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;
    my ($status, $password) = $r->get_basic_auth_pw;
    return $status if $status != Apache::OK;
    my $user = $r->user;

    my $file = $r->uri;
    $file =~ s|^/sites/([^/]*/[^/])*|$1/users.file|;

    if (open(P, $file)) {
        while (<P>) {
            chomp;
            next if /^#/;
            my ($name,$saved_pw) = split /:/;
            next if $user ne $name;
            if ($saved_pw ne crypt($passwd,$saved_pw)) {
                last;
            }
            return Apache::Const::OK;
        }
        close P;
    }

    return Apache::Const::DECLINED;
}

1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not a 100% answer to my question but it's probably the best answer I will get and at least this will give me some context to investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean directing HTTP requests according to the site to a different DocumentRoot, ScriptAlias and CustomLog, or do you need something more complex? Could you please provide more details about your Location directives?

Something worth trying might be mod_macro (http://www.coelho.net/mod_macro/)

Comment: mod_macro might be something but it still needs a definition for every location (although it's much less). It also needs a reload or the server every time you add a new definition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at using [`<LocationMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch)?

It's the regex big brother of `<Location>`. If there is enough structure to your existing  directives then it should be possible to match them with a single regex.

Comment: Sorry, <LocationMath /> is not going to work for me.